# Error is Cannot find module '@angular/fire'.ts(2307)

Tags: angular, firebase

how to resolve cant find @angular/fire
when import
it said that cant find module @angular/fire

how to resolve cant find @angular/fire
it said that cant find module @angular/fire

```
npm i firebase @angular/fire --save

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Is this `npm i firebase @angular/fire --save` what's actually in your code? You need to run that command in the console, not put it in your code.

Comment: when i  use npm i firebase @angular/fire --save .... it just add package.json file in @angular/fire ....all other files are not added

Comment: when you ran `npm i firebase @angular/fire --save` in the terminal, did the install process complete successfully?

Comment: i executed npm i firebase @angular/fire --save     in terminal and the process completed , but it just add package.json in @angular/fire/package.json..... no other file is installed

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2c3Li.png based on this seems like the install didn't go so well. Try deleting your node_modules folder, and redo the install? just run `npm i` in the project folder. After that you can rerun `npm i firebase @angular/fire` and share the output here.

Comment: i made several new project and follow the said steps ...but same problem occurs.

Comment: are you sure the `npm i` didn't give any errors?

Comment: yes , npm didnt give any errors

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/apOpUne